# Sending UDP packet with ESP32

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

I'm trying to send a UDP packet to my Milights (wifi LED bulbs via bridge) to controll them. The packets do not show up in Wireshark though.

When I change the destination ip of the UDP packet to the one of my PC then it works. I can find the packet in Wireshark then.

```
/*
 *  This sketch sends random data over UDP on a ESP32 device
 *
 */
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

// WiFi network name and password:
const char * networkName = "********";
const char * networkPswd = "********";

//IP address to send UDP data to:
// either use the ip address of the server or 
// a network broadcast address
const char * udpAddress = "********";
const int udpPort = ********;

//Are we currently connected?
boolean connected = false;

//The udp library class
WiFiUDP udp;

byte command[27] = {0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x16, 0x02, 0x62, 0x3A, 0xD5, 0xED, 0xA3, 0x01, 0xAE, 0x08, 0x2D, 0x46, 0x61, 0x41, 0xA7, 0xF6, 0xDC, 0xAF, 0xD3, 0xE6, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E};

void setup(){
  // Initilize hardware serial:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Connect to the WiFi network
  connectToWiFi(networkName, networkPswd);
}

void loop(){
  //only send data when connected
  if(connected){
    //Send a packet
    udp.beginPacket(udpAddress,udpPort);
    udp.write(command, 27);
    udp.endPacket();
  }
  //Wait for 1 second
  delay(1000);
}

void connectToWiFi(const char * ssid, const char * pwd){
  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi network: " + String(ssid));

  // delete old config
  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  //register event handler
  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);

  //Initiate connection
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pwd);

  Serial.println("Waiting for WIFI connection...");
}

//wifi event handler
void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event){
    switch(event) {
      case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
          //When connected set 
          Serial.print("WiFi connected! IP address: ");
          Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  
          //initializes the UDP state
          //This initializes the transfer buffer
          udp.begin(WiFi.localIP(),udpPort);
          connected = true;
          break;
      case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
          Serial.println("WiFi lost connection");
          connected = false;
          break;
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain to me why I CAN send messages UDP packets to my PC and not to my Wifi bridge?

Comment: What are the IP addresses you're trying to send to?

Comment: @JohnRomkey 192.168.31.101 (works) 192.168.31.182 (doesn't work)

Comment: And wireshare is running on the .101 machine? Did you try an UDP broadcast as well (.255)? Because IIRC chances are that your UDP packet is actively routed to the correct address instead of made available to every network participant if a specific target is defined.

Comment: Did you try to send an UDP first with netcat from the same network to discard any networking issue ?
echo "test message" |nc -w1 -u IP_ADDRESS UDP_PORT